# How would I loop this

Tags: c#

I've modded in custom 'origins' (character classes) to a game and they do show up in-game. Then I tried to add functionality to them. When you click on a origin, you spawn in as a certain character. For example, if i choose a origin "Hank J Wimbleton" in the character creator menu, then i spawn as hank in-game. It works when it isn't in a loop, but copy and pasting the code would take too long, and make the file size bigger because theres a lot of characters in the game. I've tried to loop it but the code returns either the first character of the list or the last one. (crackpot is first and swamp zed is last).

List 'characters' contains all the characters in the game.
array named 'array' contains a character named 'arena'

Expected results:
the code should change "arena" to the character you choose when choosing origin.

my explaining skills are quite bad but i got a screenshot that i hope will clear up some questions:

[image]

Choosing The Sheriff should spawn you in as The Sheriff
The character names on the origins on the left side of the screenshots repeat because theres different versions of one character, with different armor and size. The have been named like that by the devs.

What code i tried:

```
   array[0].myOrigin = this.selectedOrigin.myOrigin;
            for (int j = 1; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                if (array[0].myOrigin.FullName == list[j].FullName)
                {
                    array[0] = Char_Data.CreateCharacter(characters[j]);
                }
            }
```

FullName is a string.

myOrigin is the origin that you click on.

The code works when its not in a loop:

```
if (array[0].myOrigin.FullName == list[5].FullName)
                    {
                        array[0] = Char_Data.CreateCharacter(characters[5]);
                    }
```

and spawns you in as the character you chose.

Comment: What should be stored in `array[0]`? The first one that matches? The last one that matches?

Comment: The problem with the loop is that it overwrites the value in `array[0]` for every match which is why you end up with the last one when using the loop. If you want it to stop after the first match use the keyword `break` inside the `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the loop is that it overwrites the value in `array[0]` for every match which is why you end up with the last one when using the loop. If you want it to stop after the first match use the keyword `break;` inside the if statement.

```
array[0].myOrigin = this.selectedOrigin.myOrigin;

for (int j = 1; j < list.Count; j++)
{
    if (array[0].myOrigin.FullName == list[j].FullName)
    {
        array[0] = Char_Data.CreateCharacter(characters[j]);
        break;
    }
}
```

This will assign the first matching item to `array[0]` and then exit the loop.